# The coEilenbeg-Moore category of an Eilenberg-Moore category

Tags: ct.category-theory, locally-presentable-categories

Take a category $\mathcal{C}$ with a monad $T$ and construct the the Eilenberg-Moore category $\mathcal{C}^T$, the adjunction that arises is the terminal splitting of the monad $M$. Denote the resulting comonad on $\mathcal{C}^T$ as $S$, one can now construct its co-Eilenberg-Moore category $(\mathcal{C}^T)^{S}$ and there is a unique functor $L:\mathcal{C} \to (\mathcal{C}^T)^{S}$.

This seems to be a fairly canonical construction that somebody must have looked at before. I'm particularly interested in the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is locally presentable and the monad is accessible - it follows that case that $\mathcal{C}^{TS}$ is presentable and $L$ is accessible.

Comment: Did you have a specific question? One not terribly difficult result is that if one takes a monad $M$ on $Set$ and passes to the co-Eilenberg-Moore category over $Set^M$, then one gets $Set$ back provided that $F(!): F(0) \to F(1)$ is a regular monomorphism in $Set^M$ but not an isomorphism. This condition holds in a great many examples. The result is due to Mesablishvili -- see the nLab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comonadic+functor

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thanks for pointing out that material - I was able to prove a much stronger result than I had expected.

Answer (score 1):

This situation is studied in detail in Pavlovic–Hughes's [The nucleus of an adjunction and the Street monad on monads](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.07353) and applied to study the Dedekind–MacNeille completion in [Tight limits and completions from Dedekind-MacNeille to Lambek-Isbell](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.09285) by the same authors.

Comment: Oh wow, this is a deep cut. Now I have to try and remember why I was thinking about that…